# Granular permission in Kibana on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, kibana

## Background

### Wiring

I have an Elasticsearch cluster on AWS Elasticsearch Service. It has a Kibana endpoint enabled. Cognito provides the AWS role based on the user's group.

### Cognito groups and AWS roles

The AWS role that is set to the group `viewer` by AWS Cognito is `arn:aws:iam:123:role/kibana-viewer`.

The AWS role that is set to the group `admin` by AWS Cognito is `arn:aws:iam:123:role/kibana-admin`.

### Desired restriction

Only `admin` group should have access to a specific index pattern when using Kibana to view the data. The limited index Elasticsearch pattern is `secret-*`.

The `viewer` group should *not* be able to access `secret-*` via Kibana.

## Question

How can I prevent only the role `arn:aws:iam:123:role/kibana-viewer` from accessing `secret-*` index pattern in the AWS Elasticsearch cluster?

## What I have tried

### First attempt

Setting the following statement in access policy:

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam:123:role/kibana-viewer"
  },
  "Action": "es:*",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:es:my-region:123:domain/my-domain/*"
}
```

The `viewer` was able to access index `secret-1`.

### Second attempt

Setting the above `Resource` to `arn:aws:es:my-region:123:domain/my-domain/secret-*`, a `viewer` can't login due to:

```
User: x:x:x::xx:x is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpGet
```

### Third attempt

Setting both statements:

```
{
  "Effect": "Deny",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam:123:role/kibana-viewer"
  },
  "Action": "es:ESHttpGet",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:es:my-region:123:domain/my-domain/secret-*"
},
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam:123:role/kibana-viewer"
  },
  "Action": "es:ESHttpGet",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:es:my-region:123:domain/my-domain/*"
}
```

A `viewer` can login to Kibana but can't see any data due to `403` error on API call `_plugin/kibana/api/saved_objects/?type=index-pattern&per_page=10000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to solve it using AWS Elasticsearch.

However, I was able to get the desired result usin `Open Distro for Elasticsearch` on `EC2`. Also wrote a [detailed blog post about it](https://medium.com/@navatm/tutorial-elasticsearch-kibana-secured-and-cheap-76f1d63a7597).